# Haskell : Parsing with a fixed syntax along with user defined options

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, avro

I'm currently using [AVRO](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/spec.html) implementation in Haskell [here](https://github.com/GaloisInc/avro) as a reference and (re)implementing my own version to do a relatively big project in Haskell.

The `Type` that is defined for representing Schema is [this.](https://github.com/GaloisInc/avro/blob/master/src/Data/Avro/Schema.hs#L66)

I would like to also have an option for the user of this library to have "custom" defined fields to be added as part of the JSON schema. These "custom" fields are NOT relevant for producing Haskell data structures and serialization based on the AVRO specification. As an example, lets say we have an infra, when  that generates "logging" functions (used when doing the RPC defined in AVRO spec), based on "log" key with value true being present as part of the schema. If we don't want to log a field, we can leave out the "log" key.

```
      {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "test",
          "fields" : [
                       {
                        "name": "a", 
                        "type": "long"
                       },
                       {
                        "name": "b", 
                        "type": "string",
                        "log" : true
                      }
                     ]
      }
```

Now the parser that generates "AVRO" related stuff, does NOT care about the keywords it does not understand. But the User infra, to which these makes sense will need to parse these.

what is the best way to do represent the AST and construct this by applying multiple parsers, 1. the regular "avro" parser and then the user defined parser to look for "custom" syntax. Some thing like below (for a way smaller set)

```
    import           Data.Aeson
    data AvroObj a = Record Name [AvroObj a]
                  | Enum Name Symbols a
                  | Boolean Name a
                  | Integer Name a
                  | Float Name a
                  deriving(Show)

    data UserState = UserState {
       log :: Maybe Bool
    } deriving(Show)

-- this is defined in the library
    instance FromJSON a => FromJSON (AvroObj a) where
        parseJSON = undefined

-- user defines this 
    instance FromJSON UserState where
        parseJSON = undefined
```

Somehow the user can use `AvroObj UserState` type to refer to the complete AST. I'm stuck at defining the type and what the function signatures should be.
Any pointers to some patterns dealing with this would be great.

Thanks.